# How to get next week monday to sunday in my sql

Tags: php, mysql, date, joomla

I am using below code for fetching next monday but i am unable to fetch next sunday on same week. like today is friday and if i search next week then i need to get next week monday to sunday.

```
SELECT now() + INTERVAL 7 - weekday(now()) DAY
```

This above give me next monday.

I need to add 7 more days and get sunday date in same format.

> 2018-07-30 14:45:43 Monday
>
> 2018-08-05 14:45:43 Sunday

Comment: _"add 7 more days and get sunday"_ If you're on a Monday and you add 7 days, you're going to end up back on a Monday...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add 6 days to get the sunday of the monday. Add 13 days to add the second sunday after the monday:

```
SELECT (now() + INTERVAL 7 - weekday(now()) DAY) + INTERVAL 6 DAY;
```

Answer (score 4):

The `strtotime()` function is great for vague relative queries like this:

```
$monday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next monday'));
$sunday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next monday + 6 days'));
```

Yields:

```
2018-07-30
2018-08-05
```

Comment: Yeah, but that's PHP and not SQL.

Comment: The question is tagged PHP and OP did not ask for a SQL-specific solution.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have gotten "2018-07-30 14:45:43" and need to get Sunday. Sunday is *six* days after Monday, so just add 6 to 7 and get 13.

`SELECT now() + INTERVAL 13 - weekday(now()) DAY`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
select monday, monday + interval 6 day as sunday from
(select now() + INTERVAL 7 - weekday(now()) DAY as monday) s1
```